# ansible echo to terminal when condition is found

Tags: regular-expression, debugging, ansible

How can I have the output printed to the terminal when condition is met using lineinfile

```
- lineinfile:
    path: /home/pc/date.txt
    state: present
    line: 'yes'
    regexp: '^\s*Wednesday\s*$'
  check_mode: yes
  register: wednesdayOccur
- debug: msg="{{ wednesdayOccur.stdout }}" #Show on terminal "wednesday is found"
  when: wednesdayOccur == 1
```

Comment: you register `wednesdayOccur` but then use some different variable in the `when` clause... why?

Comment: With the issue that @thrig mentioned now being fixed in your playbook (changing `wednesday` to `wednesdayOccur` in the `when:` condition), do you still have the same problem?

Comment: The error is stating "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. 
The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\nThe error appears to be in 
'/home/pc/bin/prac.yaml'"

Comment: `lineinfile` does not return `stdout`, I can't really tell what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Given the file

```
# test.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - lineinfile:
      path: /tmp/blah
      state: present
      line: 'yes'
      regexp: '^\s*Wednesday\s*$'
    check_mode: yes
    register: wednesdayOccur
  - debug: msg="wednesday is found"
    when: wednesdayOccur is defined
```

This produces, among other things,

```
$ printf Wednesday'\n' > /tmp/blah
$ ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR=1 ansible-playbook test.yml
...
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "wednesday is found"
}
...
```

Which is how Ansible presents debug output.

If you need something from the variable, each module does its own thing,
so you must consult the fine manual for each module e.g. [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html), or,
log the variable with `debug` to see what it happens to contain for the
given conditions:

```
# test2.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - lineinfile:
      path: /tmp/blah
      state: present
      line: 'yes'
      regexp: '^\s*Wednesday\s*$'
    check_mode: yes
    register: wednesdayOccur
  - debug: msg="wednesdayOccur"
    when: wednesdayOccur is defined
```

this produces, among other things,

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "backup": "",
        "changed": true,
        "diff": [
            {
                "after": "",
                "after_header": "/tmp/blah (content)",
                "before": "",
                "before_header": "/tmp/blah (content)"
            },
            {
                "after_header": "/tmp/blah (file attributes)",
                "before_header": "/tmp/blah (file attributes)"
            }
        ],
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "line replaced"
    }
}
```

and then you'll have to puzzle out how to make use of that.